# ROBOT FRAMEWORK: [Error] Parsing ___.robot failed: Data source does not exist

Tags: python, test-design, test-strategy, robotframework, debugging

I just setup `Robot Framework` yesterday. I went to `YouTube` to see some videos on how to set up and I found one that was just uploaded last month. I follow all the steps and I numbered it below.

1. Installed `Python 2.27` and added it on `Environmental Variables`
2. Installed `RobotFramework (3.0.2)` using `pip install robotframework` (CMD run as Administrator)
3. Installed `Selenium 2 Library` using `pip install robotframework-selenium2library`
4. Downloaded the browser drivers (`ChromeDriver`, `GeckoDriver` and `IE Driver`) and added on `Environmental Variables`.
5. Dowloaded the [Robotframework Database-Libary](http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/) ZIP, then extracted the downloaded zip file
6. In CMD, I then key in `python setup.py install` (SUCCESS)
7. Next, I installed the `database APIs` through `pip install py mssql` (SUCCESS)
8. NOW, I downloaded `PyCharm Community 2016.3` Installed `IntelliBot` plugin on `PyCharm`

I have created a project `FirstProject`. Under it I created a directory `testsuite`. In testsuite, I created my `testcase1.robot` and copy pasted some sample robot framework test on the editor and run it using command `pybot testcase1.robot`.

However, I encountered an error saying

```
[ERROR] Parsing 'testcase1.robot' failed: Data source does not exist.
```

Here's my code.

It'll simply open `Facebook` website through `Chrome` browser.

========================================================================

```
*** Settings ***

Documentation This is my first robot framework test script

Library Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***

open browser  http://www.facebook.com  chrome

close browser

*** Keywords ***
```

======================================================================= Regardless of my code, I have the next questions:

1. Did I miss something on my configuration?
2. If not, what's wrong with the code?
3. If fixed, will that make my test run?

Any feedback is well appreciated.

Comment: I have the exact same issue but On my Mac.

Comment: Presuming the whitespace in the original source is ok (is mangled here in SO), the error must probably comes from the way you try to start the particular case. Can you share the command you use to execute it.

Answer (score 3):

"data source does not exist" simply means that you gave a filename to robot, and robot can't find that file.

For example:

```
$ pybot /path/to/non-existent/file
[ ERROR ] Parsing '/path/to/non-existent/file' failed: Data source does not exist.
```

That means that either:

1. the file truly does not exist. For example, maybe you forgot to save the file
2. you misspelled the filename
3. you spelled the filename correct, the file exists, but it is in a different directory than the current working directory.

The first thing to do is to verify if the file exists. For example, you could type `ls testcase1.robot` and see if it shows up. If `ls` can't find the file, neither can robot.

The other thing to do is to `cd` to the folder that contains the test. That should solve the problem.

The final solution is to simply give the full path to the test.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you run the robot or pybot command from folder other than the one which contains your .robot tedt suite.

Navigate to the folder which contains the test suite and then run the pybot/ robot command.

You can also download RIDE - pip install robotframework-ride - It is the best IDE for robot framework if you are using windows machine.

Comment: I would argue that RIDE is the absolute worst IDE for robot. Pycharm is considerably better, as is RED (based on eclipse), brackets (brackets.io), and many others.

Comment: With it's specific and brittle configuration RIDE is truly no longer the editor of choice on any platform, including windows. The others out there mentioned by @BryanOakley provide more functionality or a more complete development experience.

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can do
go to terminal-->next to local click on + button
and run your program

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem today, as well. The commands I use is:

```
robot someTest.robot --variablefile /path/to/my/resource
```

But it fails with:

```
[ ERROR ] Parsing '--variablefile' failed: File or directory to execute does not exist.

Try --help for usage information.
```

But when I `robot someTest.robot` or `ls /path/to/my/resource`, I can run the test/check the file.

Then I changed it to:

```bash
# -V = --variablefile
robot -V /path/to/my/resource someTest.robot
```

And it starts to work. So the error message is misleading.